# Can I use Organization Lightning Component inside the managed package component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, managed-package

In my case, I am deveoping a managed package. My customers download my managed package. And I want my customers can add their own lightning component to the managed package.

I am planning that I can get customers lightning component name via custom settings. And, I want to add component dynamically to managed package.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 6):

The managed package can't be updated in the subscriber's org, but you can gain access to subscriber components via [`$A.createComponents`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_dynamic_cmp_async.htm). The caveat, of course, is that the `access` of the component in question must be `global` in order for you to successfully gain access to it.

```
({
  someControllerMethod: function(component, event, helper) {
    $A.createComponents([["c:someComponent", {}]], $A.getCallback(function(createdComps) {
      component.set("v.body", createdComps);
    }));
  }
})
```

Where `c:someComponent` will be gained from your custom setting, label, or whatever you decide to use.

Comment: Thank you @sfdcfox, I can add org's lightning components to managed package dynamically. However, I see that even if I set attributes, the component is displayed without attribute values. Why does it happen? I am creating ui components with attributes, they works perfectly. But for this component I cannot set attributes on dynamically created.

Comment: @efirat The attributes must also have `access="global"` or they cannot be set.